# equivalent semaphore decrement on iphone

Tags: iphone, multithreading, semaphore

I found the following semaphore example. I'm currently learning about thread syncing. I have few questions.

1) If a semaphore is initilized with a value of zero and I call semaphore_down is the semaphores values now -1 or does semaphore_down simply check if the value is greater than zero then block?

2) I'm coding for IOS and there is no semaphore_down function avaiable. What is the equivelent? Is it the same as semaphore_wait?

I want to have a producer thread running for ever, waiting when it does not need to produce and waking when it does without blockin other threads.

This seems like what I need but suggestions are welcome.

```
 void reader_function(void);
    void writer_function(void);
    char buffer;
    Semaphore writers_turn;
    Semaphore readers_turn;
    main()
    {
    pthread_t reader;
    semaphore_init( &readers_turn );
    semaphore_init( &writers_turn );
    /* writer must go first */
    semaphore_down( &readers_turn );
    pthread_create( &reader, pthread_attr_default,
    (void *)&reader_function, NULL);
    writer_function();
    }
    void writer_function(void)
    {
    while(1)
    {
    semaphore_down( &writers_turn );
    buffer = make_new_item();
    semaphore_up( &readers_turn );
    }
    }
    void reader_function(void)
    {
    while(1)
    {
    semaphore_down( &readers_turn );
    consume_item( buffer );
    semaphore_up( &writers_turn );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attempt to wait on a semaphore with a value of 0, it will never go negative -- it will always block until another thread posts to the semaphore to increment it, at which point your thread will wake up and decrement it.

What semaphore library are you using?  A semaphore object generally only supports two operations: *post* and *wait*, and optionally also initialization and deinitialization methods.  So, based on the names, your `semaphore_wait` *should* be the same as `semaphore_down`, but it's impossible to say without seeing your semaphore library's documentaiton.

iOS also has [POSIX semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview), which you could use instead.

Comment: well the example was from a book excerpt and doesnt say what library it is. I will try semaphore_wait and see what happens. using posix on ios it is impossible for a semaphore to be less than 0?

Comment: On any system, it is impossible for a semaphore count to be less than 0.  If the count is less than 0, it is not a semaphore.